# Mongoose: How can I reference a nested schema that is in a separate file?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

If two schemas are in the same file, you can reference it with: [AccountSchema]. You can see that in the "accounts" property of the UserSchema.

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
import Account from './accounts'


let AccountSchema = new Schema ({
  accountName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: [true, "You already have an account with this name."],
  },
  percent: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    required: true
  },
  isGoal: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  accountHistory: {
    type: Array
  }
})


let UserSchema = new Schema ({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "This username is taken."],
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "This email is already being used."],
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  infusions: {
    type: Array,
    timestamps: true
  },
  accounts: {
    type: [AccountSchema],
    count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 8
    }
  },
  secretToken: {
    type: String
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
})

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
export default User
```

But what do you do if the schemas are in separate files? How can you reference them? I tried like this, but it didn't work:

```
// account.js
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let AccountSchema = new Schema ({
  accountName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: [true, "You already have an account with this name."],
  },
  percent: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    required: true
  },
  isGoal: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  accountHistory: {
    type: Array
  }
})

const Account = mongoose.model('users', AccountSchema)
export default Account
```

And the User schema in a separate file with:

```
  // users.js
  import express from 'express'
  import mongoose from 'mongoose'
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema
  import Account from './accounts'

  let UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: {
      type: String,
      unique: [true, "This username is taken."],
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: [true, "This email is already being used."],
      trim: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    infusions: {
      type: Array,
      timestamps: true
    },
    accounts: {
      type: [Account],
      count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 8
      }
    },
    secretToken: {
      type: String
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
  })

  const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
  export default User
```

In one article I was told to export the schema, not the model that references the schema, but they did not give any idea as to how to achieve that.

Comment: Try removing this line `const Account = mongoose.model('users', AccountSchema)` from your `account.js` file

Comment: And ya also make last line as `export default AccountSchema`

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much Pavan Vora!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing below line from your account.js file

```
const Account = mongoose.model('users', AccountSchema);
```

And change the last line to this

```
export default AccountSchema;
```